# Missing header values while using to_csv function

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I am trying to read excel files using python and writing each sheet's data into separate csv file.
I am able to write the whole data but its just I am unable to get the header values.
Is there any way this can be resolved.
Here is the piece of code I am writing.

```
    xyz.to_csv(f, index=False, header=None)
```

Comment: I tried making the header parameter value as 'True' also, but that also didn't work.

Comment: You'll have to give us an example of how your csv file looks like.

Comment: Actually the source is an excel file and  i am writing each sheet as a different csv in S3.

Comment: Then please show example of your dataframe, i.e. show us what xyz looks like. You can change the actual data to maintain privacy. We need to see if you are actually reading the header into your dataframe in the first place. Also show us your code for reading the excel file